# How to enter a CURSOR in the oracle sql developer binds?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have some SQL code that I'm trying to run in Oracle SQL Developer.

However, when it opens a Report Binds window, what do I put on my cursor?
[IMAGE EXEMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Xnkf.png)

IN V_IN_DATE_START I am putting the date normally but in V_CURSOR how do I enter that it will be a cursor?

I'm running the cursor like this:

```
    OPEN :V_CURSOR FOR
```

I tried writing CURSOR and putting it there and it didn't work, I tried leaving it NULL and it didn't work either

Comment: I don't know. But, if you shared some more code (so that we'd see what you are trying to do), some ideas might pop up.

Answer (score 1):

There is no point trying to pass data to a cursor because a cursor is for returning data from the database and not inputting data. Therefore, you do not want to use the user-interface to try to set a cursor bind variable.

Instead, use the SQL*Plus (and SQL Developer) command [`VARIABLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#i1211948) to define a bind variable on the client and use that to return the cursor into:

```sql
VARIABLE v_cursor REFCURSOR;

BEGIN
  OPEN :V_CURSOR FOR
    SELECT * FROM DUAL;
END;
/

PRINT v_cursor;
```

And then you could use the SQL*Plus (and SQL Developer) command `PRINT` to print the contents of the cursor.

Then, in SQL Developer, run the worksheet as a script using <kbd>F5</kbd> (and not running a single statement using <kbd>Ctrl + Enter</kbd>).